# SDK version 32 to version 33

Tags: android

I am working on a project that has compileSdkVersion 32 and I want to change it to compileSdkVersion 33, I am a bit new working with android and I do not understand if I should only change this number or what else should I change in my project and if I should change something else what should I do to have full compatibility with that version 33, the project is completely in compose and occupies hill for dependency injection and has an MVVM architecture, I would like to know if I should also change the number of library versions, I would really appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: change that version and see if you get new errors. Also read https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13

Comment: There is something I don't clear, I need to ask the permission for notifications adding code and ask it like other permissions or just add the permission in the manifest?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission - that's more than I know about it:)